# Is it possible to make a GET request with a body in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I made an API that reads data from a database based on a given `id` via a GET request.

It gets some data where `id` equals some integer.

I want to call this API in Flutter using `package:http/http.dart` but the GET request doesn't allow me to enter a request body (where I would pass in the `id`).

I've Googled and Googled to no avail (I may just be googling the wrong thing). I tried changing my API to a POST rather than GET, which works, but I feel it defeats the purpose of GET.

Here is how I do it using POST:

```dart
String url = "http://example.com/api/v1";
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};

String json = '{"id": 1}';

Response response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
```

But can I achieve this with GET in Flutter?

Comment: use http://example.com/api/v1/?pram1=valu1&pram2=valu2&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Request` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Request-class.html) for this:

```dart
final request = Request('GET', 'http://example.com/api/v1');

request.body = '{"id": 1}';

final response = request.send().stream.first;
```

Alternatively, you can also use idiomatic syntax, i.e. standard procedure, and provide your parameter in the URI:

```dart
await get('http://example.com/api/v1?id=1', headers: headers, body: json);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Works like a charm :)

Comment: It is definitely not a standard to send a body via a GET request! That's how we get totally crazy APIs out there, that are a pain in the ass to implement.

Comment: Check out https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.3 : "The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI."

Comment: RFC2616 has been deprecated. RFCs 7230 to 7237 is the new hipness. The point, however, still stands.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot  Future<EmployeeIfscDetail> getEmployeeIfscDetail(BuildContext context,String ifsc,String token) async {
    var _response = await _employeeModel.getEmployeeIfscDetail(jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{APIKey.IFSC: ifsc}),token);
  ..
} trying to fetch data like this but its giving error all time -    Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: []("BankName")

Comment: @Ephenodrom I agree, but I wanted to answer the question nonetheless. It is also why I included the idiomatic approach.

Answer (score -1):

There is a dart package that provides some helper classes for http requests.

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

Install it with:

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.5.1
```

It is also part of the EZ-Flutter Collection :

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter
Docs : https://ez-flutter.de/docs

```
dependencies:
  ez_flutter: ^0.2.5
```

In your case, you can't send a body within a GET request. You have to set the id in the url you are calling. 
Usage

```dart
Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Some": "Header"
};
Map<String, String> queryParameters = {
  "Some": "Parameter"
};

String url = "example.com/api/v1/something/;
String id ="100"
url = url + id;


    Map<String, dynamic> reaponseBody;
    try {
        responseBody = await HttpUtils.getForJson(url,
        queryParameters: queryParameters, headers: headers);
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle exception, for example if response status code != 200-299
    }
    // do something with the response body
```

Additional information :

These are all methods from the HttpUtils class.

```dart
Future<Map<Response> getForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getForJson(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> getForString(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<Response> postForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> postForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response> putForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> putForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> putForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response deleteForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> deleteForJson(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> deleteForString(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Map<String, dynamic> getQueryParameterFromUrl(String url);
String addQueryParameterToUrl(String url, Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters);
```